# Convert point from coordinate system screen to x y

Tags: system, frame, coordinate

Convert point from coordinate system to  java ,

in Java Frame
+-------x
|
|
|
y

I want it as this one

y
|
|
+------x

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can   change it, let y = Ymax - y

```
  public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        Canvas canvas = (Canvas) e.widget;
        int maxX = canvas.getSize().x - 20;
        int maxY = canvas.getSize().y - 20;
        e.gc.setForeground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
        int h = 0;
        int pixelCount = 4;
        e.gc.drawLine(50, maxY, maxX, maxY);

        e.gc.drawLine(50, maxY, 50, 0 + 20);
```